# Bash script to know when my phone extensions are unreachable?

Tags: shell-script, asterisk

Is there anyway to write a bash that can notify me via email when my phone extensions are unreachable?

Output from `/var/log/asterisk/full`

```
[Nov 15 13:25:16] NOTICE[7884] chan_sip.c: Peer '7778' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 17
[Nov 15 13:25:17] NOTICE[7884] chan_sip.c: Peer '7169' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 17
[Nov 15 13:25:17] NOTICE[7884] chan_sip.c: Peer '7176' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 18
[Nov 15 13:25:18] NOTICE[7884] chan_sip.c: Peer '7771' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 14
[Nov 15 13:25:18] NOTICE[7884] chan_sip.c: Peer '7606' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 17
[Nov 15 13:25:18] NOTICE[7884] chan_sip.c: Peer '7773' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 14
[Nov 15 13:25:19] NOTICE[7884] chan_sip.c: Peer '7125' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 15
[Nov 15 13:25:20] NOTICE[7884] chan_sip.c: Peer '7772' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 15
[Nov 15 13:25:22] NOTICE[7884] chan_sip.c: Peer '7605' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 16
[Nov 15 13:25:22] NOTICE[7884] chan_sip.c: Peer '7183' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 18
[Nov 15 13:25:29] NOTICE[7884] chan_sip.c: Peer '7601' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 24
[Nov 15 13:25:30] NOTICE[7884] chan_sip.c: Peer '7776' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 47
[Nov 15 13:25:32] NOTICE[7884] chan_sip.c: Peer '7604' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 25
[Nov 15 13:25:34] NOTICE[7884] chan_sip.c: Peer '7774' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 46
[Nov 15 13:25:38] NOTICE[7884] chan_sip.c: Peer '7770' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 41
[Nov 15 13:25:41] NOTICE[7884] chan_sip.c: Peer '7775' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 42
```

As you can see, I don't know the phones are down until people complain they can't make a phone call.

What I have done so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

email="myemail@mydomain.com"

offlineExtensions=$(cat /var/log/asterisk/full | grep -i unreachable)


if [ "$offlineExtensions" ]
then
printf 'Extensions that are currently offline...\n''\n'"$offlineExtensions" | mail -s 'Extensions OFFLINE' "$email"
fi
```

I would like to use `sed` and `awk`, but I'm brand new to bash scripting.

It would be nice if this script is constantly checking the `Asterisk log file` to find out if an extension is unreachable.

Comment: Marc, it's not polite to "move the goalposts" of a question; if Stéphane's answer solved your original question, the right thing to do is to accept it and then open a new & separate question with your "Update".

Comment: I apologize Jeff, my fault. I have since edited the question and opened a separate question. Stephane did answer my question and I'm thankful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of looking at the logs, ask `asterisk` directly which extensions are not OK

```
asterisk -rx 'sip show peers like ^[0-9]{4}$' | awk 'NR>1 && !/ OK /'
```

Would report the 4 digit extensions that are not "OK".

Comment: I've added an update to my original question. Your one-liner is perfect for what I want to do. How can I change that to reflect the update I've added to my question, please?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple `one-liner` that can do what you want:

```
tail -F /var/log/asterisk/full | while read -r line; do if [[ "$line" == *NREACHABLE* ]]; then mail -s "$line" admin@somedomain.tld </dev/null ; fi; done
```

Run this within `screen` or `tmux`.

Or:

```
#!/bin/bash

    while read -r line
     do if [[ "$line" == *NREACHABLE* ]]; then 
         mail -s "$line" admin@somedomain.tld </dev/null 
        fi 
     done < <(tail -F /var/log/asterisk/full)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you wouldn't want to put a `tail -F` job into cron every minute.

Comment: @JeffSchaller you are right. `tail -F` isn't meant to be put as a cron job. I was planning to customize the script so it works without `tail -F` and queries the log every minute but Stephane seems to have the answer using asterisk itself which is of course the preferred way.

Comment: Hi all, thank you so much for your answers and comments. Which would be best to use @Stephanes or the while statement from @val0x00ff?

Answer (score 0):

The script below can do what you are looking for. I have used `sendmail` to send notifications by email.
Set this script to run as a `cron` job, it will check for unreachable extensions and will send you email notifications when unreachable extensions are > 0

```
#!/bin/bash

email="myemail@mydomain.com"
/usr/sbin/asterisk -rx 'sip show peers' > /tmp/allExtensions.txt
offlineExtensions=`cat /tmp/allExtensions.txt| grep 'UNREACHABLE'`
count=`cat /tmp/allExtensions.txt | wc -l`
if [ $count -gt 0 ]; then
(
echo "Subject: Offline Extensions"
printf 'Extensions that are currently offline...\n''\n'"${offlineExtensions}"
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail ${email}
fi
```